# Intellij: Runtime components are missing in JavaFX project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying, on a windows machine, to create a .jar file from a project that I created. I can create the .jar file throght jlink and the use of a custom jar {} to compact all the jars in one .jar file.

When I try to run the .jar file that I have obtained I get the error: the required runtime components of javaFX are missing for this application. I even tryied to include the directory of JavaFX directyly in the .jar file, but I wasn't able to resolve the error.

Otherwise if I run the project from the main class I don't encounter this error. Is there a way to insert the Runtime components of JavaFX directly in the .jar file?

Here you can see my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'application'
id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.preventivoApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.preventivoapp.appproject_preventivo'
    mainClass = 'com.preventivoapp.appproject_preventivo.QuoteMainApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")

    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.15.0'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.15.0'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.15.0'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.28'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task copyJavaFXLibs(type: Copy) {
    from 'C:\\Users\\dcfre\\Downloads\\javafx-sdk-17.0.8\\lib'
    into 'libs'
}

jar {
    dependsOn copyJavaFXLibs
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class' : 'com.preventivoapp.appproject_preventivo.QuoteMainApplication'
    }
    from {
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Any help would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here are the [157 times this question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Runtime+components+are+missing%22), if you review them, you should find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I found out it was pretty simple. I followed this [guide](https://gist.github.com/RyanKoech/15e2dd446f5424c2fe86249e5528289d)

and I was also able to use the same .jar file to create .exe file of my project using lauch4j.

Comment: Please include a summary of the colloquy cited.